# Visual Studio Team Services - Allow specific members to publish repos

Tags: azure-devops

We need to allow a certain group of users in our VSTS subscripts to create repositories.  How is this accomplished?  The security is very confusing :(  Thanks

Comment: What's the result after you specifying Administer permission for certain group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add that group into the security group of the top-level Git repositories and then give it "Administer" permission:
[image]

> **Permission - Administer**
>
> Can rename and delete the repository. If assigned to the top-level Git
>   repositories entry, can add additional repositories.
>
> At the branch level, users can set permissions for the branch and
>   unlock the branch.

Answer (score 0):

A user has [Administer](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/permissions#git-repository) permission of Git repository can create repository. So you just need to grant Administer permission of specific repository to the user or group.